# What will happen if the locks themselves get contended upon?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

All objects in Java have intrinsic locks and these locks are used for synchronization. This concept prevents objects from being manipulated by different threads at the same time, or helps control execution of specific blocks of code.

**What will happen if the locks themselves get contended upon - i.e. 2 threads asking for the lock at the exact microsecond.**

Who gets it, and how does it get resolved?

Comment: Where did you get this notion of `intrinsic locks`?

Comment: if 2 threads want the same lock in the exact "nanosecond", then the thread which requests/asks for it first will get it... provided some other thread is not holding it..

Comment: @Craig In the Oracle site itself. If you're not familiar with the concept, read about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: This is a bit broad for here, a complete answer would be a chapter in a book on concurrency. The short answer is that there is no "exact same time" - its an atomic operation done with CPU support

Comment: I'm familiar with the subject, just never heard it called that (worked with synchronisation mainly in C#)

Comment: @BrianRoach Please post it as the answer, actually this info: "an atomic operation done WITH CPU support." satisfies me enough. Makes sense as it's possible that the JVM manages this internally by synchronizing stuff directly in the CPU registers.

Comment: @QuestionEverything what you're actually asking about are mutexes. Here's a good lite stating point I found via a quick google http://mortoray.com/2011/12/16/how-does-a-mutex-work-what-does-it-cost/

Comment: @BrianRoach Got it, thanks for the link. As of now, I'm already satisfied. I'll venture into more detail in your link on Saturday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What will happen if the locks themselves get contended upon - i.e. 2 threads asking for the lock at the exact microsecond.

One thread will get the lock, and the other will be blocked until the first thread releases it.

<sup>(Aside: some of the other answers assert that there is no such thing as "at the same time" in Java.  They are wrong!!  There is such a thing!  If the JVM is using two or more cores of a multi-core system, then two threads on different cores *could* request the same Object lock in *exactly* the same hardware clock cycle.  Clearly, only one will get it, but that is a different issue.)</sup>

> Who gets it, and how does it get resolved?

It is not specified which thread will get the lock.

It is (typically) resolved by the OS'es thread scheduler ... using whatever mechanisms that uses.  This aspect of the JVM's behaviour is (obviously) platform specific.

If you really, really want to figure out precisely what is going on, the source code for OpenJDK and Linux are freely available.  But to be frank, *you don't need to know*.

Comment: On the same clock cycle in multi-core you still don't have "at the same time" at the memory access level when talking about mutexes (because if you did you'd be hosed). The bus arbitrator is going to determine which core "wins" and gets access to the memory. That's what I was eluding to in my (non-answer) comment :)

Comment: @BrianRoach - Even if there is a piece of hardware that decides which core "wins" when updating a single memory cell, the fact remains that the two cores *did* reach the finishing line at the same time.  That is what >>I<< mean.  Certainly, your point about arbitrating (write) access to the same memory cell does not apply in more general cases ... which is what my point is about.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to concurrency, there is no such thing as "at the same time"; java ensures that *someone* is first.

If you are asking about simultaneous contended access to lock objects, that is the essence of concurrent programming - nothing to say other than "it happens by design"

If you are asking about simultaneously using an object as a lock *and* as a regular object, it's not a problem: It happens all the time when using non synchronized methods during a concurrent call to a synchronized method (which uses `this` as the lock object)

Answer (score 1):

The thing handling lock requests can only handle one thing at a time; therefore, 2 threads can't ask for the lock at the same time.

Even if it is in the same microsecond, one will still be ahead of the other one (perhaps faster by a nanosecond). The one that asks first will get the lock.  The one who asks second will then wait for the lock to be released.

An analogy will be ... stacking papers together... Suppose I have one hand and that hand can only hold one piece of paper. Different people(threads) are handing me a single piece of paper.  If two people "offer me papers at the same time" I will handle one before the other

In reality, there is no such thing as at the same time.  The phrase exists because our brains can not work at the micro...nano...pico second speeds

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Answer (score 1):

Locks are implemented not only in JVM but also at OS and hardware level so the mechanisms may differ. We rely on Java API and JVM specs and they say that one of the threads will acquire the lock the other will block.